# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value in redis

Tags: php, redis

I am using php with Redis. When I am trying to access a key by get method then get following error:

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

I am using the following code to access the hasekey value - I use this code to get data from redis

```
$values = "l_messages"

$value = $redis->GET($values)

print($value)
```

Comment: What redis library are you using?

Comment: Predis library are using

Comment: Is this the exact code? Please update if not.  A string `"l_messages"` should not cause a problem.   put a `var_dump($values)` right  before the line `$value = $redis->GET($values)`

Comment: i use this command get single value return $value = $redis->rpop($values), but use this command  $value = $redis->get($values) not return value

Answer (score 3):

This error means your object's data type is different and you are using a wrong operation to retrieve the key.

If **l_messages**  is a **hash map** and you need to retrieve all its values you need to use **hgetall**. If it's a **set** you have to use **smembers**. Similarly for each type of key you have to use different commands.

You can use **type** command to know the type of that particular object.

See this for complete reference : https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-redis-in-php-using-predis/